# Dymanic listview construction visible in jQuery Mobile 1.4.2 transition

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview, jquery-mobile-ajax

I have a Single Page transition from #homepage to #addresses where the page #addresses include a dynamic listview build based in an $.ajax WebApi call.

The problem is that it's visible the construction of the listview when we arrive at the second page, and I want to avoid that, I want the list all build when we land in the #addresses page.

I also have a delay click in the listview in iPhone.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>izigo.mobile</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function ()
        {
            $.mobile.toolbar.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;
            $.mobile.toolbar.prototype.options.backBtnText = "voltar";
            $.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = true;
        });

    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        /* Pass data with changePage */
        $(document).on("pageinit", "#homepage", function ()
        {
            $(".category").on("click", function ()
            {
                $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#addresses",
                    {
                    categoryId: this.id,
                    transition: "slide"
                });
            });
        });

        /* retrieve data and run function to add elements */
        $(document).on("pagebeforechange", function (e, data)
        {
            if (data.toPage[0].id == "addresses")
            {
                var categoryId = data.options.categoryId;

                clearListCategory("#addresses");
                buildListCategory("#addresses", categoryId);
            }
        });

        function clearListCategory(page)
        {
            var $page = $(page);

            $("ul", $page).remove();
        }

        function buildListCategory(page, categoryId)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://10.0.0.200/api/Mobile/GetAddresses",
                crossDomain: false,
                beforeSend: function () { $.mobile.loading('show') },
                complete: function () { $.mobile.loading('hide') },
                data: { CategoryId: categoryId },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (addresses)
                {
                    showAddresses(page, addresses);
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("loadList error!");
                }
            });
        }

        function showAddresses(page, addresses)
        {
            var $page = $(page);

            var list = $("<ul/>", {
                "data-role": "listview"
            });

            var items = '';

            $.each(addresses, function (i, address)
            {
                items = $("<li>" + address.Name + "</li>");
                list.append(items);
            });

            $(".ui-content", $page).append(list);
            $("ul", $page).listview();
        }
    </script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

    <!-- home-page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="homepage">

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"><h1>mobile</h1></div>

        <div class="ui-content" role="main">

            <ul data-role="listview" id="categories">
                <li><a href="#" id="3" class="category">Oficina</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="100" class="category">Seguro</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="101" class="category">Reboque</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- page addresses list -->
    <div data-role="page" id="addresses">

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"><h1>mobile</h1></div>

        <div class="ui-content" role="main"></div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can run the function on `pagecontainershow`.

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/S87Hw/

Comment: Hi Omar, thanks but the listview is only build when the second page is loaded (transition happens, then it shows the loader and then the listview), and I just want to make the transition after the listview is complete

Comment: From your OP, I understood that you want to populate listview when `#addresses` is fully load and visible. you want to move from `#home` to `#addresses` when the listview is loaded?

Comment: yes, only when the #addresses page listview is complete

Comment: But here you're passing params in `pagebeforechange`, which means _transition_ is triggered. You need to handle this in Ajax `success` function, to move to `#addresses` once Ajax call is successful.

Comment: here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/n9Px4/show/) and [code](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/n9Px4/). In the demo, page is changing after a successful Ajax call (dummy call).

Comment: Great! it's working! I was having problem with 1.3.x because the href in #homepage was firing transtion and in 1.4.x it seems that this don't happen. Any ideia about the delay on click on iPhone? Thank you again!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51417/discussion-between-omar-and-patrick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you're using, you populate *listview* on `pagebeforechange` event, which is triggered before any other *page event*. You should populate *listview* before you navigate to target page, using `.success` or `.complete` callback.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "URL",
    crossDomain: false,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $.mobile.loading('show')
    },
    complete: function () {
        $.mobile.loading('hide')
    },
    data: {
        CategoryId: categoryId
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (addresses) {
        showAddresses(page, addresses);
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#addresses");
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("loadList error!");
    }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/n9Px4/show)** - **[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/n9Px4/)**